# Doxygen addtogroup issue with a special function FUNC(..)

Tags: c, doxygen

I have embedded system C code and I used doxygen to document using addtogroup command. When reviewing the html output, one of the function after special function FUNC(..) is not appear in module page. Here is a short sample code.

```
    /*!
      \addtogroup Test
      \brief This is a TestModule
      \{
     */
    extern FUNC(void, IOHWAB_APPL_CODE) Init_Tester(void);

    void TimerOn(void)
    {
    }
    void ADC_On(void)
    {
    }

    /*! \} */ //end of addtogroup
```

On the example above, the doxygen shows only the following.

> extern FUNC(void, IOHWAB_APPL_CODE) 
>  void ADC_On(void)

If I add a *dummy function (i.e. void dummy())* in between extern FUNC(..) and void TimerOn(), all the functions are shown except the dummy function.

> extern FUNC(void, IOHWAB_APPL_CODE) 
>   void TimerOn(void) 
>  void
>   ADC_On(void)

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have test the following code:

```
/*!
  \addtogroup   Test
  \brief        This is a TestModule
  \{
 */
extern FUNC(void, IOHWAB_APPL_CODE) Init_Tester(void)
{
}

void Timer(void){}

void TimerOn(void)
{
}

void ADC_On(void)
{
}

/*! \} */ //end of addtogroup
```

And I get the document like this:

```
> Functions     
>FUNC (void, IOHWAB_APPL_CODE)   
>void Timer (void)   
>void TimerOn (void)   
>void ADC_On (void)
```

If I change the function implement into declare, the function in document disappeared.
It's seemed that the doxygen only document the implement for function, and it parse the TimerOn's implement for FUNC incorrectly. So, miss the TimerOn function in the document.

I am not sure, just test it and guess the result. Hope this can help you.